# Subtracting values between "columns" in RDD tuples - error: overloaded method value - with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to subtract two "columns" of multiple RDD 3tuples in Scala. However I get this error when I try to subtract r - a in the code:

```
overloaded method value - with alternatives:
[error]   (x: Double)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Float)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Long)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Int)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Char)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Short)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Byte)Double
[error]  cannot be applied to (AnyVal)
[error]   val newnom = userRatings.leftOuterJoin(newUserAverages).map { case (u, (r, a)) => (u, r - a.getOrElse())}
```

Code:

```
  val userRatings = train.map(x => (x._1, x._3))
  val userAverages = userRatings.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map{case (u, r) => (u, (r.sum/r.size).toDouble)}
  val newnom = userRatings.leftOuterJoin(userAverages).map { case (u, (r, a)) => (u, r - a.getOrElse())}
```

The rdd tuples looks like this before map is applied (why I use .getOrElse on ._3 elements):

```
(451,(1.0,Some(2.7362637362637363)))
(451,(4.0,Some(2.7362637362637363)))
(451,(2.0,Some(2.7362637362637363)))
(451,(4.0,Some(2.7362637362637363)))
(451,(4.0,Some(2.7362637362637363)))
```

I basically want the last value to be subtracted from the second, which I hope is clear from the text. Tried to convert the numbers in multiple ways, rounding, formatting etc.. but keep getting the same error.

Comment: I believe in the getorelse statement you need to put a value for the "else" case, and this value should be a number (e.g. 0). Now it is claiming an AnyVal because the return type of getorelse is not defined. Didn't try myself, let me know if it works so I post the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Used asInstanceOf[Number].doubleValue which probably work for similar overload errors.